# Problem creating a pivot table on all machines

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

> Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method

I create an excel macro that involves creating a pivot table and configuring it. The macro runs fine on my machine in the workbook I created it in, but it does not work on the machine it will mainly be used on. They are the same type of machine with the same version of Windows and Microsoft Office.

Below is the full pivot table chunk of VBA code, and the line that throws the error is:
`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Meter Read Date").AutoGroup`

I suspect it might be the .AutoGroup method, but I don't know VBA well enough or have enough experience with macros to know how to fix it and no other online research is helpful.

```
Dim dataname As String
Dim newsheet As String

    dataname = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).Name

    Sheets.Add
    newsheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        dataname, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=newsheet & "!R3C1", _
        TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets(newsheet).Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Type")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Meter Read Date")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Meter Read Date").AutoGroup
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Type")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Meter Read Date")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Years").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Quarters").Orientation = _
        xlHidden
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Service Street Addr")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("kWh"), "Sum of kWh", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Therms"), "Sum of Therms", xlSum
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("MMBtu")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Bill Amt"), "Sum of Bill Amt", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("MMBtu"), "Count of MMBtu", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of MMBtu")
        .Caption = "Sum of MMBtu"
        .Function = xlSum
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Type").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Type").CurrentPage = _
        "Agency Building"
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Service Street Addr"). _
        AutoSort xlAscending, "Service Street Addr"
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you running this code with? `PivotField.AutoGroup` appears to have been introduced in Excel 2016... see answer below.

Comment: "They are the same type of machine **with the same version of** Windows and **Microsoft Office**." - I challenge that. Error 438 wouldn't be happening *just on some machines* if everybody was using the same version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *type* the expression `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Meter Read Date").AutoGroup`, you'll notice that you don't get any autocompletion after `ActiveSheet.` - that's because `ActiveSheet` is not necessarily a `Worksheet`, and its data type is `Object`: every single member call that follows it can only be resolved at run-time.

That's what I call *implicit late binding*, and it's a very common trap... with a rather simple solution: be as *explicit* as possible about the data type of *everything*, and refuse to work with an `Object` unless you *must*.

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet
```

Now we can make a compile-time validated member call against`sheet`. Problem is, `.PivotTables.Item` (a hidden, implicit default member that's accepting the `"PivotTable2"` parameter) *also* returns an `Object` - so we need a `PivotTable` reference:

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Set pt = sheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
```

Now we get to make compile-time validated member calls against `pt`... and we see that `.PivotFields.Item` *also* yields an `Object` - so we need a `PivotField` reference:

```
Dim ptField As PivotField
Set ptField = pt.PivotFields("Meter Read Date")
```

And now we can make an early-bound member call...

```
ptField.AutoGroup
```

Now, `PivotField.AutoGroup` appears to have been introduced in Office 2016, so an early-bound member call will not compile at all in an earlier version - because *the member effectively does not exist*... which would explain your error 438.

Anyway now we get to reuse all these objects everywhere we need them, instead of re-dereferencing them *every single time* off the `ActiveSheet`. Your code, all early-bound except for the `AutoGroup` member call, which will only run if Excel is version 16.0 or higher:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet 'TODO See https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/code-name-sheet1/

Dim newSheet As Worksheet
Set newSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'NOTE: .Add returns the new Worksheet object reference

Dim tableName As String
tableName = sheet.ListObjects(1).Name

Dim ptCache As PivotCache
Set ptCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
    SourceData:= tableName, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Dim pt As PivotTable
'NOTE: PivotCache.CreatePivotTable returns the new PivotTable reference
Set pt = ptCache.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=newSheet.Name & "!R3C1", _
    TableName:="PivotTable2", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

Dim typeField As PivotField
Set typeField = pt.PivotFields("Type")
typeField.Orientation = xlRowField
typeField.Position = 1

Dim meterReadDateField As PivotField
Set meterReadDateField = pt.PivotFields("Meter Read Date")
meterReadDateField.Orientation = xlRowField
meterReadDateField.Position = 2

Dim lateBoundExcel2016 As Object
Set lateBoundExcel2016 = meterReadDateField
If Application.Version >= 16 Then
    lateBoundExcel2016.AutoGroup
Else
    'PivotField.AutoGroup member is not available in Excel < 2016.
End If


'TODO figure out if these are redundant
typeField.Orientation = xlPageField 'was set to xlRowField above
typeField.Position = 1
meterReadDateField.Orientation = xlPageField 'was set to xlRowField above
meterReadDateField.Position = 1 'was set to 2 above, and TypeField is 1??

Dim yearField As PivotField
Set yearField = pt.PivotFields("Years")
yearField.Orientation = xlHidden

Dim quarterField As PivotField
Set quarterField = pt.PivotFields("Quarters")
quarterField.Orientation = xlHidden

Dim serviceAddressField As PivotField
Set serviceAddressField = pt.PivotFields("Service Street Addr")
serviceAddressField.Orientation = xlRowField
serviceAddressField.Position = 1 'suspicious

Dim mmBtuField As PivotField
Set mmBtuField = pt.PivotFields("MMBtu")
mmBtuField.Orientation = xlRowField
mmBtuField.Position = 2

Dim kwhField As PivotField
Set kwhField = pt.PivotFields("kWh")
pt.AddDataField kwhField, "Sum of kWh", xlSum

Dim thermField As PivotField
Set thermField = pt.PivotFields("Therms")
pt.AddDataField thermField, "Sum of Therms", xlSum

Dim billAmountField As PivotField
Set billAmountField = pt.PivotFields("Bill Amt")
pt.AddDataField billAmountField, "Sum of Bill Amt", xlSum

pt.AddDataField mmBtuField, "Count of MMBtu", xlCount

typeField.ClearAllFilters
typeField.CurrentPage = "Agency Building"

serviceAddressField.AutoSort xlAscending ', serviceAddressField.Name '<~ optional argument is redundant
```

Comment: Thank you! Save for the Year and Quarter clauses, this worked. I do believe there is a difference in the microsoft office updates between the two machines.